# Alarmmanager after reboot - putExtra

Tags: android, alarmmanager, reboot

I have few things working fine in my app:

- I set my `AlarmManager` to create notifications in my main activity's `OnCreate`. Notifications are based on certain dates. That works great.
- I send dates to alarmmgr for notification by putting extra to intent. That works great
- I have implemented `onBootReceiver` that gets called properly after device rebot.

My intention was to start the `AlarmManager` with `onBootReceiver` to activate alarm again.

**Problem:** - I'm originally sending dates from my `MainActivity` to `AlarmManager` but that data is not available (or is it?) in my `onBootReceiver` to create new intent with extras and start new alarm.

How can I use `onBootReceiver` to restart the similar/same alarm after reboot, that I normally create in my activityMain??

Comment: in your `MainActivity` where do you get the data that you send in the intent extra? (post relevant code)

Comment: I have some data in sharedpreferences and some data in sqlite databases.

Comment: ok, then get that data in the `onBootReceiver`

Comment: i advice you to store that data in to sharedpref or database, i was facing same problem but this idea helped me.

Comment: I  can do that. Is that good programming practice? Then I'll have similar code settibg alarmManager in my onBootReceiver and onCreate on activityMain? Can there be some conflicts or dual alarms?

Comment: you can put a flag in sharedPrefs, that alarms were added. do it in `onBootReceiver` and check for it in `MainActivity`